# Spark streaming sourceArchiveDir does not move file to archive dir

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

How to move source CSV files into archive directory using "sourceArchiveDir" and "cleanSource=archive"? I am running below code, but it does not move source file, however stream processing is working fine, i.e. it prints source file content to console.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}

val inputPath = 
  "/<here is an absolute path to my project dir>/data/input/spark_full_delta/2021-06-21"

spark
.readStream
.format("csv")
.schema(jsonSchema)
.option("pathGlobFilter","customers_*2021-06-21.csv")
.option(
  "sourceArchiveDir", 
  "/<here is an absolute path to my project dir>/data/archive")
.option("cleanSource", "archive")
.option("latestFirst","false")
.option("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.cleaner.numThreads", "2")
.option("header", "true")
.load(inputPath)
.withColumn("date", lit("2021-06-21"))
.writeStream
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
.format("console")
.start()
```

StructSchema for reference:

```
scala> jsonSchema
res54: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
StructField(customerId,IntegerType,true), 
StructField(name,StringType,true), 
StructField(country,StringType,true), 
StructField(date,DateType,false))
```

Documentation reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets. Scroll down to the table of source with their options.

Answer (score 1):

File source archiving is based on several more internal Spark options, which you can try to change (but you do not have to) for debugging purpose to speed up the source files archiving process:

```scala
spark
.readStream
.format("csv")
.schema(jsonSchema)
// Number of log files after which all the previous files 
// are compacted into the next log file.
.option("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.log.compactInterval","1")
// How long in milliseconds a file is guaranteed to 
// be visible for all readers.
.option("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.log.cleanupDelay","1")
.option(
  "sourceArchiveDir", 
  "/<here is an absolute path to my project dir>/data/archive")
.option("cleanSource", "archive")
...
```

then try to add more files to the source path. Spark should move already seen files from previous micro-batch to "sourceArchiveDir".

Please note, both options (compactInterval, cleanupDelay) are Spark internal options, which may change in future without any notice. Default values as of Spark 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT:

```
spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.log.compactInterval: 10
spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.log.cleanupDelay: 10 minutes
```